# VBA Regex to format a string

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I want to delete all spaces, parenthesis (open and close), dot and dash in a string, I try to do a regex that make this but no success.
Can you help me ?

Comment: 1. Show us the code 2. What was the outcome / difference to your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A RegEx that matches what you are looking to remove would be:

```
/[ \(\)\.-]/g
```

If you would like to match any form of whitespace instead of just a simple space, use \d in place of the single space (first character after the opening square bracket).

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**
regex: `([\s\(\{\[\)\}\]\.\-]+)`

[Live Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vR7hT2/2)

I use in **php:**

```
$re = "/([\\s\\(\\{\\[\\)\\}\\]\\.\\-]+)/m";
$str = "park fdgh{dg df} df \n";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to **RegEx** consider:

```
Sub StringFixer()
    ary = Array("(", ")", " ", ".", "-")
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        For Each a In ary
            t = Replace(t, a, "")
        Next a
        r.Value = t
    Next r
End Sub
```